# How to Fix Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock Error on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

I have recently started learning linux commands and got this error while installing any application on Ubuntu.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to install app?
Did you use apt?

If so, maybe some other apt process is running in the background or you have opened Synaptic package manager.

Run `sudo killall apt apt-get` and please try again

Answer (score 0):

if another package is in progress for installation/removal then in that case you are going to install/remove second one package you will face Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock error

Answer (score 0):

try starting in recovery mode then install muon package manager then install programs from it insted synaptic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).